# Getting information that vmmap gets with a program on Mac OS

Tags: macos, kernel, virtual-memory, low-level, mach

I was trying to print all the memory regions of a process using the `mach_vm_region` and it seemed to work fine but when I compared it to the vmmap command `vmmap -v -interleaved <PID>,` I realized that I was still missing many memory regions.

For instance, after my program and vmmap were giving the same memory regions for about 50 regions straight, , in a certain region my program got this:

```
180000000 to 1f8000000
1f8000000 to 1f869c000
1f869c000 to 1f86bc000
1f86bc000 to 1f86c0000
1f86c0000 to 1fa000000
1fa000000 to 1faeac000
1faeac000 to 1fc5a0000
1fc5a0000 to 1ff928000
1ff928000 to 200000000
```

while in the same space, vmmap got this:

```
Submap                      180000000-1f8000000    [  1.9G     0K     0K     0K] r--/r-- SM=SHM          machine-wide VM submap
unused shlib __TEXT         1a2174000-1a21c5000    [  324K   324K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__TEXT                      1a21c5000-1a21c7000    [    8K     8K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
__TEXT                      1a21c7000-1a2209000    [  264K   264K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
__TEXT                      1a2209000-1a2223000    [  104K   104K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
__TEXT                      1a2223000-1a22ad000    [  552K   536K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
__TEXT                      1a22ad000-1a22d8000    [  172K   172K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
__TEXT                      1a22d8000-1a231f000    [  284K   284K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
__TEXT                      1a231f000-1a235d000    [  248K   248K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
__TEXT                      1a235d000-1a2360000    [   12K    12K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib
__TEXT                      1a2360000-1a23e2000    [  520K   488K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
__TEXT                      1a23e2000-1a2449000    [  412K   396K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
__TEXT                      1a2449000-1a2461000    [   96K    96K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
__TEXT                      1a2461000-1a2499000    [  224K   224K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
__TEXT                      1a2499000-1a24a6000    [   52K    52K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
__TEXT                      1a24a6000-1a24b3000    [   52K    52K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
__TEXT                      1a24b3000-1a24bb000    [   32K    32K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
__TEXT                      1a24bb000-1a24e8000    [  180K   164K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
__TEXT                      1a24e8000-1a2a2f000    [ 5404K  4092K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
unused shlib __TEXT         1a2a2f000-1a4921000    [ 30.9M  17.4M     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__TEXT                      1a4921000-1a4bd7000    [ 2776K  2568K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib

...

__DATA_DIRTY                1fb3fe3e8-1fb3fe3f0    [     8      8      8     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
__DATA_DIRTY                1fb3fe3f0-1fb3fe404    [    20     20     20     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
unused shlib __DATA         1fb3fe404-1fb400000    [    7K     7K     7K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          unused system shared lib __DATA, on dirty page
__DATA_DIRTY                1fb400000-1fb405838    [   22K    22K    22K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
__DATA_DIRTY                1fb405838-1fb405848    [    16     16     16     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
__DATA_DIRTY                1fb405848-1fb405cb8    [  1136   1136   1136     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
__DATA_DIRTY                1fb405cb8-1fb406708    [  2640   2640   2640     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
unused shlib __DATA         1fb406708-1fb408000    [    6K     6K     6K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          unused system shared lib __DATA, on dirty page
__AUTH                      1fb408000-1fb4081b8    [   440    440     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
__AUTH                      1fb4081b8-1fb408218    [    96     96     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
unused shlib __DATA         1fb408218-1fb40c000    [   15K    15K     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __DATA not used by this process
__AUTH                      1fb40c000-1fb414000    [   32K    32K     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
__DATA                      1fb414000-1fb415400    [    5K     5K     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
__AUTH                      1fb415400-1fb415478    [   120    120     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
__AUTH                      1fb415478-1fb416190    [  3352   3352     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
__AUTH                      1fb416190-1fb418628    [    9K     9K   1576     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
__AUTH                      1fb418628-1fb418670    [    72     72     72     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
__AUTH                      1fb418670-1fb4186b0    [    64     64     64     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
__AUTH                      1fb4186b0-1fb418880    [   464    464    464     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
__AUTH                      1fb418880-1fb41a740    [    8K     8K     8K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
unused shlib __DATA         1fb41a740-1fb41c000    [    6K     6K     6K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          unused system shared lib __DATA, on dirty page
unused shlib __DATA         1fb41c000-1fb4a2640    [  538K   506K     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __DATA not used by this process
__AUTH                      1fb4a2640-1fb4a2660    [    32     32     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
__AUTH                      1fb4a2660-1fb4a2668    [     8      8     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
unused shlib __DATA         1fb4a2668-1fbb2c000    [ 6694K   982K     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __DATA not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fbb2c000-1fbc08e80    [  884K   884K     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
__OBJC_CONST                1fbc08e80-1fbc0f9f0    [   27K    27K     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
unused shlib __DATA         1fbc0f9f0-1fc288000    [ 6626K  1250K     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __DATA not used by this process
__OBJC_RW                   1fc288000-1fc5a0000    [ 3168K  1616K    16K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5a0000-1fc5a0030    [    48     48     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
__OBJC_CONST                1fc5a0030-1fc5a0390    [   864    864     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
__DATA_CONST                1fc5a0390-1fc5a4e20    [   19K    19K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
__OBJC_CONST                1fc5a4e20-1fc5a5f90    [    4K     4K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5a5f90-1fc5a6c90    [  3328   3328     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
__OBJC_CONST                1fc5a6c90-1fc5a6e40    [   432    432     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5a6e40-1fc5a7f10    [    4K     4K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5a7f10-1fc5a84e8    [  1496   1496     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fc5a84e8-1fc5a8500    [    24     24     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__DATA_CONST                1fc5a8500-1fc5bb8e8    [   77K    29K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
__OBJC_CONST                1fc5bb8e8-1fc5bc938    [    4K     4K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fc5bc938-1fc5bc940    [     8      8     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5bc940-1fc5bd3c8    [  2696   2696     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
__OBJC_CONST                1fc5bd3c8-1fc5bd698    [   720    720     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5bd698-1fc5bd808    [   368    368     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5bd808-1fc5be168    [  2400   2400     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5be168-1fc5c02a8    [    8K     8K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5c02a8-1fc5c34b8    [   13K    13K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5c34b8-1fc5c35e0    [   296    296     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5c35e0-1fc5c3810    [   560    560     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5c3810-1fc5c3fc8    [  1976   1976     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5c3fc8-1fc5c4250    [   648    648     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc5c4250-1fc5c53f0    [    4K     4K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fc5c53f0-1fc6e1e10    [ 1139K   947K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fc6e1e10-1fc6f3d48    [   72K    72K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fc6f3d48-1fc6f41c8    [  1152   1152     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fc6f41c8-1fc70fa80    [  110K   110K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fc70fa80-1fc70fe00    [   896    896     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fc70fe00-1fc896a40    [ 1563K  1451K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fc896a40-1fc897608    [  3016   3016     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fc897608-1fc8e5718    [  312K   136K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fc8e5718-1fc8e6160    [  2632   2632     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fc8e6160-1fc9af288    [  804K   724K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fc9af288-1fc9af560    [   728    728     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fc9af560-1fcae6480    [ 1244K   892K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fcae6480-1fcae78c0    [    5K     5K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fcae78c0-1fcbf6250    [ 1082K   842K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fcbf6250-1fcbf6560    [   784    784     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fcbf6560-1fcbf6768    [   520    520     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fcbf6768-1fcc3f8b8    [  292K   212K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fcc3f8b8-1fcc3f9c0    [   264    264     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fcc3f9c0-1fccc6ac0    [  540K   268K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fccc6ac0-1fccc6d50    [   656    656     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fccc6d50-1fccf2d88    [  176K   144K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf2d88-1fccf2da8    [    32     32     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fccf2da8-1fccf2e28    [   128    128     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf2e28-1fccf2e98    [   112    112     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
unused shlib __TEXT         1fccf2e98-1fccf2fb0    [   280    280     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf2fb0-1fccf3d80    [  3536   3536     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf3d80-1fccf3e98    [   280    280     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf3e98-1fccf4168    [   720    720     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/liboah.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf4168-1fccf45a0    [  1080   1080     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf45a0-1fccf4600    [    96     96     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf4600-1fccf4750    [   336    336     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_collections.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf4750-1fccf4a18    [   712    712     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf4a18-1fccf4b78    [   352    352     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf4b78-1fccf4bf8    [   128    128     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf4bf8-1fccf4db0    [   440    440     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf4db0-1fccf4e70    [   192    192     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf4e70-1fccf5120    [   688    688     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf5120-1fccf5208    [   232    232     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libfakelink.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                1fccf5208-1fccf5260    [    88     88     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftLinking.framework/Versions/A/SoftLinking
unused shlib __TEXT         1fccf5260-1ff928000    [ 44.2M  6603K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
Submap                      1ff928000-200000000    [ 7008K     0K     0K     0K] r--/r-- SM=PRV          process-only VM submap
```

Now I understand `submaps` and that all of these mini regions only happened after vmmap specified that the `REGION TYPE` (first column) was of type `Submap` and I did try along using `mach_vm_region_recurse` with depth greater than 0 however that only gave this:

```
1a2174000 to 1f1b30000
1f3b30000 to 1f669c000
1f869c000 to 1f86bc000
```

that was extra information - nothing even close to vmmap. I did try looking around and the closest thing I could try to find to fix this problem was the `segment_command_64` struct defined as :

```
struct segment_command_64 { /* for 64-bit architectures */
    uint32_t    cmd;        /* LC_SEGMENT_64 */
    uint32_t    cmdsize;    /* includes sizeof section_64 structs */
    char        segname[16];    /* segment name */
    uint64_t    vmaddr;     /* memory address of this segment */
    uint64_t    vmsize;     /* memory size of this segment */
    uint64_t    fileoff;    /* file offset of this segment */
    uint64_t    filesize;   /* amount to map from the file */
    vm_prot_t   maxprot;    /* maximum VM protection */
    vm_prot_t   initprot;   /* initial VM protection */
    uint32_t    nsects;     /* number of sections in segment */
    uint32_t    flags;      /* flags */
};
```

along side the `getsectbynamefromheader_64` function but I really couldn't figure anything out as there is 0 documentation for anything.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing Mach-O segments, there is a fair bit of information out on the web about the Mach-O executable **file format**, which is what you're dealing with here, it's just mapped directly into memory.

Essentially though, each Mach-O segment (`segment_command_64`) will contain some number of sections (`section_64`). The sections are described in an array of `section_64` structs immediately following the `segment_command_64` struct. There will be `nsects` array entries. You can skip from segment to segment by moving `cmdsize` bytes ahead in memory. (The number of load commands you will encounter is specified in the `ncmds` field of the `mach_header_64` file header. They won't all be segments (`cmd == LC_SEGMENT_64`) but share the `load_command` struct prefix.

The other thing to bear in mind about `vmmap` is that it has a whole bunch of special security entitlements which allow it more access to kernel APIs and data structures than most processes:

```
$ codesign -d --entitlements - /usr/bin/vmmap 
Executable=/usr/bin/vmmap
??qq?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.private.iosurfaceinfo</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.private.security.storage.AppDataContainers</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.iokit-user-client-class</key>
    <array>
        <string>IOSurfaceRootUserClient</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.system-task-ports</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.system-task-ports.read</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.system-task-ports.read.safe</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.system-task-ports.safe</key>
    <true/>
    <key>task_for_pid-allow</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However most of that is for allowing inspection of *other* processes - I'm not sure if those entitlements enable it to view more information than a regular process can get about *itself*.